# Telegram bot api: how to list all active users

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

Is there any way to gather all users, who send `/start` command to bot in any time by http API?

I am trying to build remainder-bot and thinking if this is necessary to save all of them in local database.

I am using python-telegram-bot for now. BTW any answer will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```
# create a dictionary to save users who sends start command
users= {}

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext): 

    global users

    user= update.message.from_user

    # get userid and username
    id= user['id']; name= user['username']
    # save them in a dictionary if they aren't already saved
    if id not in users.keys():
        users[id]= name
```

Now you can use that information to save on a database or do other stuff you want.

Comment: Yeah, ofc. BTW i wonder omit database. If it's possible to get users without storage - it would be nice. But, seems like it's impossibru

Comment: I think what you want is get all real time active users. There is no way to do that in python-telegram-bot. But you can check typing status of users via telegram api. https://core.telegram.org/constructor/updateUserTyping .

Comment: it's not http api, but api for telegram client (not bot). Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. It not the bot api, but client api. With client api you can check the online status directly. I've somehow missed it. https://core.telegram.org/type/contactStatus . Also checkout telethon module and this tutorial, https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/ , https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-the-telegram-api-b0cd220dbed2 .